# How to match until the first occurrence of extension pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

Given the following string how to capture till the first [^\s]+ or ”.mkv”?

```
"   ss     s.mkv ss.sss.sss    s..sss.   ".match(/.+\.[^\s]+/)
```

Returns me the whole string. What I need:

```
  ss     s.mkv
```

Comment: What about `/.*\.mkv/` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [non-greedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy) repetition operator:

```
"   ss     s.mkv ss.sss.sss    s..sss.   ".match(/.+?\.[^\s]+/)
//                                                  ^
```

Alternatively, excluding the dot from your matches works just as well:

```
"   ss     s.mkv ss.sss.sss    s..sss.   ".match(/[^.\n]+\.[^.\s]+/)
```

Comment: AHH so close myself as I did play with non greedy but used it on the whole exp rather than the first wildcard. Tks so much!

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to matching, here is a way to use a `replace`:

```js
var s = "   ss     s.mkv ss.sss.sss    s..sss.   ";
var result = s.replace(/^([^.]+\.\S+)[\s\S]*/, '$1');
document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>\"" + result + "\"</pre>";
```

The regex `^([^.]+\.\S+)[\s\S]*` matches:

- `^` - start of string
- `([^.]+\.\S+)` - Group 1 (further referenced to with `$1`) matching one or more characters other than a dot (`[^.]+`) followed with a literal `.` followed with one or more non-whitespace characters (`\S+`)
- `[\s\S]*` - zero or more characters including a newline, too (up to the end of the string).